# How to show a preview of a post? (Using Jekyll Bootstrap theme)

Tags: jekyll

This is probably an easy question, but how do I show previews of my posts on the default page? I am using the Jekyll Bootstrap theme Tom.

Answer (score 49):

This also works at least as of `1.0.0`, is built in and is simple to use.

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

See [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts).

Answer (score 48):

Looking through the functions [here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers), I found strip_html and truncatewords.

Here's a sample "posts list" with 75 words of preview text.

```
<ul >
    {% for post in site.posts limit 4 %}
    <li><span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> &raquo; <a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
        {{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords:75}}<br>
            <a href="{{ post.url }}">Read more...</a><br><br>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: It does not preserve formatting. Everything is displayed as a plain text.

Comment: @mlt just take `strip_html` away

Comment: @woozyking that's not safe to do. if truncating at 75 words leaves you in the middle of some markup (ie, "this text is <b>bold and cut off"), the snippet will render that you've got a markup error. 1.0 seems to solve this with `post.excerpt` and `except_separator`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859175/how-to-show-a-preview-of-a-post-using-jekyll-bootstrap-theme/16708341#16708341

Comment: I believe jekyll uses `site.baseurl` instead of `BASE_PATH` now; also it's missing in the "Read more..." link.

Answer (score 14):

I liked the `<!--more-->` comment approach from WordPress, so I wrote something along those lines:

### _plugins/more.rb:

```
module More
    def more(input, type)
        if input.include? "<!--more-->"
            if type == "excerpt"
                input.split("<!--more-->").first
            elsif type == "remaining"
                input.split("<!--more-->").last
            else
                input
            end
        else
            input
        end
    end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(More)
```

Your post would then look like this:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Your post title"
published: true
---
<p>This is the excerpt.</p>
<!--more-->
<p>This is the remainder of the post.</p>
```

You can then use it in your templates like so:

### Show excerpt (everything above the `<!--more-->` comment):

```
<summary>{{ post.content | more: "excerpt" }}</summary>
```

### Show remainder (everything after the `<!--more-->` comment):

```
<article>{{ post.content | more: "remaining" }}</article>
```

Any argument other than `excerpt` or `remaining` will simply show the whole post.

Comment: This is already implemented im Jekyll itself: See [Jekyll: Post Excerpts](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post_excerpts). The `excerpt_separator` can be defined in the `_config.yml` file like this: `excerpt_separator: <!--more-->`

Comment: Most likely this was implemented in recent versions of Jekyll. I might be wrong but at the time of writing of this original answer, this functionality wasn't built-in.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, still would like to add a workaround for the formatting issue, as raised in @Talon876 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11044301/3363206).

At the end of each post adding closing tags like `</em>,</strong> or </b>` might not be so neat, but it maintains formatting while showing the excerpts.

For example:

```
<ul >
    {% for post in site.posts limit 4 %}
    <li><span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> &raquo; <a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
        {{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords:75}}
</em></strong>  <!-- This is what does the task-->
<br>
            <a href="{{ post.url }}">Read more...</a><br><br>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```